# Ansatz method for solving inhomogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to summarize methods for finding particular solutions, $y_p$ for inhomogeneous ODEs using Ansatz.

With $y''+y'+y=1$

An Ansatz for $y_p$ is clearly any constant C.

For  $y''+y'+y=x$

I thought an Ansatz would be $Ax+B$, where A and B are constants. But this does not work.

However, for

$y''+y'+y=e^{2x}$

we can clearly form an Ansatz $y_p=Ce^{2x}$.

So my question is , is there a rule one can make for types of inhODE such as

$y''+y'+y=x$

$y''+y'+y=x^2$

$y''+y'+y=x^n$

?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a constant coefficient ODE, and your RHS is an nth order polynomial, then guess an nth order polynomial. Also, for $y''+y'+y=x$, $y_p=Ax+b$ does work. You get $A=1$, $b=-1$.

Comment: This was indeed a clear answer. So it would work to have the same inhomogeneous term multiplied with a coefficient and adding another coefficient that vanishes upon differeniaton, that is $Ax$ plus a lower order term $A$, in a sequence $Ax^n...Ax,A$, such that we pick the two first terms when the equation is a second order diff equation, while was it a third order, we could pick also $Ax^2$ in addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A particular solution of an equation of the form
$$
y^{(n)}+a_{n_1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_0y=x^k \qquad (\star)
$$
where $a_0\ne 0$, is of the form $y_p(x)=p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$. If
$$
a_0=a_1=\cdots=a_{\ell-1}=0 \quad\text{and}\quad a_{\ell}\ne 0
$$
then a special solution of $(*)$ is of the form $y_p(x)=p(x)$, where $p(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k+\ell$.